# Moodle Assignment functionality to insert extra text in assignments

Tags: javascript, moodle

Many universities have a Blue Card scheme enabling students with specific learning difficulties (SpLDs) to flag their work with a blue card, so the tutor will mark it with due consideration.

We needed a way of making it easier for students to flag their work with a blue card, and I have come up with the following script, which goes into the Additional HTML section in Site Administration in Moodle, and works with the Moodle Assignment functionality (see previous post for [a blue card script that works with the Turnitin plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529699/moodle-turnitin-add-functionality-to-insert-extra-text-in-assignments)).

First the student clicks the button to add the blue card, which inserts a comment with the words "Blue Card" in the submission comments field. When the form is submitted, the JavaScript looks for a comment in the grading table, and adds a flag in the status column to remind the tutor to review the comments. The tutor can then display the comment and see the words "Blue Card" (which are a link to the dyslexia marking guidelines).

Comment: Here are some screenshots of what it looks like
http://obis-insights.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/using-blue-card-on-moodle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* MOODLE ASSIGNMENT BLUE CARD */

var MoodleAssignBlueCardButton =  '<input type="button" id="mabluecard" value="Flag with Blue Card" class="bluecard"/> <a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/"  target="_blank" title="What is the Blue Card scheme?">What\'s this?</a><br/>';

if (!document.getElementsByClassName('submissionstatustable')[0]) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
    var assignTable = document.getElementsByClassName('submissionstatustable')[0];
    assignTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', MoodleAssignBlueCardButton);
}

/* EVENT LISTENER FOR MOODLE ASSIGNMENT BLUE CARD BUTTON */
if (!document.getElementById('mabluecard')) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
    document.getElementById("mabluecard").addEventListener('click', function () {  
        var commentbox = document.getElementsByClassName('comment-area')[0];
        var textarea = commentbox.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
        if (!textarea.value) {
            textarea.value = ('<a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/" target="_blank" style="background-color: #99ccff">Blue Card</a>'); 
         } else if  (textarea.value == 'Add a comment...') {
               textarea.value = ('<a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/" target="_blank" style="background-color: #99ccff">Blue Card</a>'); 
       } else {
            textarea.value = ('<a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/" target="_blank" style="background-color: #99ccff">Blue Card</a>: ' + textarea.value);
         }
    /* save the comment */
    document.getElementsByClassName("comment-link")[0].click();
    var saveLink = document.getElementsByClassName("fd")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     saveLink.click();
    });
}

/* flag the Blue Card submission in the Grading Table */
if (!document.getElementsByClassName('gradingtable')[0]) {
   /* do nothing */ 
} else {
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('gradingtable')[0];
     var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

     var comments = tbody.getElementsByClassName('c10');
         for (var i=0, len=comments.length; i<len; i++){
             if (comments[i].innerHTML.includes('Comments')){
              thisRow = comments[i].parentNode;
            thisRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffcc';
            statusCell = thisRow.getElementsByClassName("c5")[0];
             statusCell.innerHTML += ' <div style="background-color: #99bbff">Student has added comments, please review</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

**NB: code is supplied 'as is' without any commitment to it being fit for purpose and is also supplied without any commitment to maintenance or support.**

([also posted on our team blog](http://obis-insights.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/moodle-assignment-blue-card.html))

**UPDATE**: To get this to work in Internet Explorer 11, I had to make the following adjustments:

```
/* flag the Blue Card submission in the Grading Table */
if (!document.getElementsByClassName('gradingtable')[0]) {
   /* do nothing */ 
} else {
     var table = document.getElementsByClassName('gradingtable')[0];
     var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var comments = tbody.getElementsByClassName('c10');
         for (var i=0, len=comments.length; i<len; i++){
             if (comments[i].innerText.search('Comments') > -1){
            thisRow = comments[i].parentNode; 
           alert('thisRow ' + thisRow);
            thisRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffcc';
            nameLink = thisRow.getElementsByTagName("a")[1]; 
            nameLink.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' <div style="background-color: #99bbff">Student has added comments, please review</div>');
             }
        }
    }
```

It also requires the following CSS to make the "Add Blue Card" button blue:

```
.bluecard {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) !important;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

This is because the [`includes()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221341/ie-does-not-support-includes-method) and the [`innerHTML()` method](http://quirksmode.org/dom/html/) do not work in IE.

Comment: Tested in IE (Edge), Chrome, and Firefox

Comment: And tested with Safari on iPhone 5

Comment: Now tested in IE 11, and adjusted accordingly